# How to interpret position in JointStateInterface

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, ros-control, diff-drive-controller, joint-state

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The context is a robot with 2 drive wheels, using the `ros_control` `diff_drive_controller`.

I would like to know if it is well defined in `ros_control` how to interpret an increasing `position` value in the `JointStateInterface`? (We'll ignore wrap-around for the moment.)

I expected that an increasing angular position value in `/joint_states` meant that the wheel was rotating counter-clockwise on its axel (as viewed from the motor side.) And therefore, when a diff drive robot moves forward in a straight line, the right wheel position value would increase, and the left wheel position value would decrease.

The commercial wheeled robot I have access to does not behave this way. For it, both wheel position values increase as the robot moves straight forward.

Are multiple conventions supported? If so, how does `diff_drive_controller` know how to interpret the values?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/382193/how-to-interpret-position-in-jointstateinterface/) by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) on ROS Answers with karma: 4903 on 2021-07-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For each wheel, an increasing value for `position` is the axel rotation that moves the robot's base_link in the +x direction. So the commercial robot got this right. The orientation of motors is ignored. I deduced this from reading the source code of `Odometry::update()` in the `diff_drive_controller` directory of `ros_control`.

---

Originally posted by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) with karma: 4903 on 2021-07-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0